# Prove or disprove each of the follow function has limits $x \to a$ by the definition $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove or disprove each of the follow function has limits $x \to a$ by the definition

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$$

Let $y = mx^2$

$$\frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}=\frac{x^4m}{x^4(1+m^2)} = \frac{m}{1+m^2}$$

Hence, $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2} = \frac{m}{1+m^2}$$

Therefore, since it depends on the value of m, the limit does not exist

Correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: A single limit might exist but if they do not agree then the main double limit does not exist.

Comment: "It depends on the value of m" is vague. You should demonstrate something specific. For example the limit is the same if $m\in \{2-\sqrt{3}, 2+\sqrt{3}\}$

Comment: @user29418: I think what you mean is that along a given path to $(0,0)$, the limit might exist. However, as the OP has shown, because one can choose multiple paths that produce results depending on the path, the limit itself doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote looks correct, but, in a sense, is technically incomplete.

Definition (or characterization) of a limit of function is as follows:

> $L$ is a limit of $f(x,y)$ at $(a,b)$ iff for every sequence
>   $(a_n,b_n)$ in the domain of $f$ without $(a,b)$ such that $(a_n,b_n) \to (a,b)$, we have $f(a_n,b_n)\to L$.

So, to complete your proof, choose sequences $(a_n, b_n) = (1/n, 0)$ (this corresponds to $m = 0$) and $(a'_n,b'_n) = (1/n, 1/n^2)$ (this corresponds to $m = 1$). Both converge to $(0,0)$, yet, from what you've shown, $f(a_n,b_n)\to 0$ and $f(a_n',b_n')\to 1/2$. Thus, the limit cannot exist.

---

There is another possible argument, which comes from change of variables for limits:

> Assume $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)$ exists and $\lim_{t\to c} g(t) =
>  (a,b)$. If $g$ is such that $g(t)\neq (a,b)$ on some punctured ball $B(c,\varepsilon)\setminus\{c\}$, then $\lim_{t\to
>  c}f(g(t)) = \lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)$.

In your case, you have $g_m(t) = (t,mt^2)$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}f(g_m(t)) = \frac{m}{1+m^2}.$ Now, choose two different values of $m$, say $0$ and $1$, and from what you have $\lim_{t\to 0}f(g_0(t))\neq \lim_{t\to 0}f(g_1(t))$, so the limits cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that correct, indeed we can consider for example

- for $x=0,\, y\neq 0 \implies \frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}=0$
- for $x=t,\,y=t^2, \,t\to 0 \implies \frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}=\frac{t^4}{t^4 + t^4}\to \frac12$