# Show that the limit does not exist $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)}\frac{5x^2}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Show that the limit does not exist $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)}\frac{5x^2}{x^2 + y^2}$

attempt:

let $y = 0$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{5x^2}{x^2 + 0^2} = 5$

let $x = 0$

$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{5(0)^2}{y^2} = 0$

$5 \neq 0$, therefore two different values, limit does not exist

right?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: The technique you've used in this question is exactly the same as the technique from [your question yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960132/prove-or-disprove-each-of-the-follow-function-has-limits-x-to-a-by-the-defini), your [question four hours ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961288/prove-or-disprove-each-of-the-follow-function-has-limits-x-to-a-by-the-defini), and likewise [12 minutes ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961500). Perhaps you could ask about a *concept* you're not sure of, rather than near-duplicated computations.

Comment: Tree.All is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is complete and you have explained your work clearly.